# Top 10 Gamers Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am looking for some help with a class I have designed for an assignment. It adds game scores to a linked list and lists them from highest to lowest. The max number of scores is 10. I have it almost working but I can't figure something out. I add the first score and it works, then if I add a second score, it only works if that score is higher than the first. If not, it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Can someone take a look at my `insert(String name, int score)` method and let me know what the problem is?

```
public class GamerList {

    /**
     * The node class stores a list element and a reference to the next node.
     * @author johnmckillip
     *
     */

    private class Node {

        String name;
        int score;
        Node next;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * @param val The element to store in the node.
         * @param n The reference to the successor node.
         */
        Node(String val1, int val2, Node n) {

            name = val1;
            score = val2;
            next = n;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * @param val The element to store in the node.
         */
        Node(String val1, int val2) {

            this(val1, val2, null);
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */

    public GamerList() {

        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    /**
     * The isEmpty method checks to see if the list is empty.
     * @return true if the list is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return head == null;
    }

    /**
     * The size method returns the length of the list.
     * @return The number of elements in the list.
     */
    public int size() {

        int count = 0;
        Node p = head;

        while(p != null) {

            count++;
            p = p.next;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public void insert(String name, int score) {

        Node node = new Node(name, score);

        if(isEmpty()) {

            head = node;
            tail = node;
        }

        else if(head.score <= node.score) {

            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }

        else {

            Node frontPtr = head.next;
            Node backPtr = head;

            while(frontPtr.score > node.score && frontPtr.next != null) {

                backPtr = backPtr.next;
                frontPtr = frontPtr.next;
            }

            if(frontPtr != null && frontPtr.score <= node.score) {

                backPtr.next = node;
                node.next = frontPtr;
            }

            else {

                frontPtr.next = node;
                tail = node;
            }
        }

        if(size() > 10) {

            Node currentPtr = head;

            while(currentPtr.next != tail) {

                currentPtr = currentPtr.next;
            }

            tail = currentPtr;
            currentPtr.next = null;
        }
    }

    public void printList() {

        Node temp = head;

        while(temp != null) {

            System.out.print(temp.name + " " + temp.score + " ");
            System.out.println("");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my class to test `GamerList`:

public class TestGamerList {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    GamerList list1 = new GamerList();

    list1.insert("Fry", 89);
    list1.insert("Bender", 25);
    list1.insert("Leela", 90);
    list1.insert("Zoidburg", 23);
    list1.insert("Amy", 34);
    list1.insert("Hermes", 96);
    list1.insert("Zapp",123);
    list1.insert("Nibbler", 56);
    list1.insert("Calculon", 12);
    list1.insert("Hypnotoad", 189);
    list1.insert("Lrrr", 5);
    list1.insert("Scruffy", 28);

    System.out.println("Top 10 Scores: ");
    list1.printList();
}
```

}

Comment: Java 6? Or Java 7? What is the class `GamerList`?

Comment: Where is GamersList insert and printList methods? Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried setting up breakpoints in your code where you add items to your linked list, and run through the program with a debugger? This will show you the issue in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @AmirKost those are in the first code fragment you have to scroll to get them

Comment: Here is the stack trace: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GamerList.insert(GamerList.java:99)
 at TestGamerList.main(TestGamerList.java:13)

Comment: Not related to your question but perhaps it's preferrable that you store a variable `size` rather to compute it everytime!

Comment: and i don't know why you need a `tail` in a single linked list.

Comment: Hi user, to get this opened back up, I'd suggest an [edit] to narrow down the scope of the problem. Instead of posting *all* your code, post just what is necessary to see the error. You should also include relevant error messages and stack traces. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't set `head`'s `next`. That's one problem. The second is, even if you do that, you'll get into infinite loop, 'cause you have done the insertion logic incorrectly. I've changed you `insert()` a bit to make it work, but that still lacks elegance and is far from effective implementation. For example, on every insertion after you've got 10 elements you are running `size()` which makes your code complexity increase by a factor of approx. `N = size()`. If you really want to do that, make `size` a variable and just increase it at the end of every `insert()`. Anyway, edited code:

```
public class GamerList {

    private class Node {

        String name;
        int score;
        Node next;

        Node(String val1, int val2, Node n) {

            name = val1;
            score = val2;
            next = n;
        }

        Node(String val1, int val2) {

            this(val1, val2, null);
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */

    public GamerList() {

        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    /**
     * The isEmpty method checks to see if the list is empty.
     * @return true if the list is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return head == null;
    }

    /**
     * The size method returns the length of the list.
     * @return The number of elements in the list.
     */
    public int size() {

        int count = 0;
        Node p = head;

        while(p != null) {

            count++;
            p = p.next;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public void insert(String name, int score) {

        Node node = new Node(name, score);

        if(isEmpty()) {

            head = node;
            head.next = tail;
        }
        else if(head.score <= node.score) {

            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }

        else {
            Node beforeNode = head;
            while(beforeNode.score > node.score && beforeNode.next != null) {
                beforeNode = beforeNode.next;
            }
            node.next = beforeNode.next;
            beforeNode.next = node;
        }

        if(size() > 10) {

            Node currentPtr = head;

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                currentPtr = currentPtr.next;
            }
            currentPtr.next = null;
        }
    }

    public void printList() {

        Node temp = head;

        while(temp != null) {

            System.out.print(temp.name + " " + temp.score + " ");
            System.out.println("");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not super clear on what I was asking. This was exactly what I could not figure out. Thanks for your help! I also changed size to a variable instead of calling the size() method every time like you suggested.

Comment: @user2827001, I suggest that you 1) read something about debugging basics (maybe in your IDE docs), and 2) read something about data structures and algorithms (maybe for beginners - don't start with Cormen or Sedgewick ;)). Good luck with that!

Answer (score -1):

Without stack trace is complex. 
but probably error is here

```
while(frontPtr.score > node.score && frontPtr.next != null)
```

since frontPtr is null.

add a check on the

```
if (frontPtr!=null)
    while(frontPtr.score > node.score && frontPtr.next != null)
```

Comment: How is that any different?

Comment: It sill throws the same exception with above change.

Comment: yep, my bad. i read it wrong.

Comment: anyway the problem is that `frontPtr` is null, as ai said before. so just check that.

Comment: i made an edit, try with that